# How to find a document that contains an apostrophe in the indexable text

Tags: google-drive-api

I use this line to build a drive query

```
request.setQ("fullText contains '" + originalFileName + "'");
```

However when the originalFilename contains a "'" the request throws this error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request {   "code" : 400,   "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "q",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "Invalid Value",
    "reason" : "invalid"   } ],   "message" : "Invalid Value" }
```

I understand why the error is thrown, but how do I build a search string to find the files that contain "faq's"in the indexable text? Is there a wildcard character, or an escape character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should escape the `'` with a `\`, so:

```
"fullText contains \'myFile\'"
```

Comment: this should be documented!

Comment: @David The documentation is here https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters

Also, this answer is misleading. as per the docs above, `contains` requires/expects `'` around the the string to be searched on. So you should **not** escape the surrounding `'`. Taking faq's as an example, the properly escaped query would look like `"fullText contains 'faq\'s'"`